# Block symbol key press jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I need to avoid symbols in text box while key is pressed, but my below code is not working. It restricted all the key events. Please help me.

```
 $('.GroupName').keypress(function (event) {
            var keycode;

            keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

            if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 27 || keycode == 219 || keycode == 220 || keycode == 221 || keycode == 222 || (keycode >= 186 && keycode <= 192)))) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#error').attr('class', 'errorMessage');
                $('#error').text("Enter Only Alphabets and Numbers. Symbols Are Not Allowed. ");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#error').attr('class', ' display: none;');
                $('#error').text("");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery there is no need to test `event.keyCode` because jQuery normalises `event.which`. Also, if you want to hide the `#error` field use `.hide()` - setting the _class_ to `display:none` won't work. Note also that the user can enter data in the field without triggering the keypress event (if they use drag'n'drop or the Edit menu).

Comment: Then how i can i correct this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find anything on my keyboard that will use those keycodes, so I created my own example. This demo restricts a lot of symbols that wouldn't typically be used in a message.

I reduced the need for conditions in the `if` statement by adding the restricted keyCodes to an array and then checking for them using `indexOf`. Also note that `event.which` is all you need to get the `keyCode`.

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/oMANuci/1/edit)**

```
var restricted = [96, 126, 40, 41, 61, 91, 93, 123, 125, 92, 124, 59, 47, 60, 62];

$('.myInput').keypress(function (event) {
  if (restricted.indexOf(event.which) !== -1) {
    console.log('key restricted!');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    console.log('key ok!'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure friend because in live demo is not restricted anything key

Comment: @Dinesh That's strange. Perhaps you have different keyCodes for some reason? Try changing out the numbers in the `restricted` array. For me, most symbols are restricted in this example.

Comment: Thank u friend is working fine but its support for ASCII Code anyway i get it thank u so much friend

Comment: @Dinesh not a clue. I've never used ASCII. You can get the keyCode by going in the `keypress` function and using `console.log(event.which)`.

Comment: You can use `console.log(event.which)` to get the code for any character you type. But note that listing out all possible _invalid_ codes is much more trouble than listing a known set of _valid_ characters given the requirement here is just letters and numbers.

Comment: @nnnnnn hmm...I got the impression that some symbols were allowed, just not all. For example `!`, `@`, `$`, etc that are more likely to be used in a normal message.

Comment: A limited number of punctuation characters is easy to add to a list of valid characters. But note that the error message in the OP's code implies no symbols of any kind. Also, in Windows anyway, the user can hold down `alt` and type a four-digit character code on the numeric keypad to type a bunch of symbols that don't have their own keys, so if you were going to list invalid characters you'd have to include all of those too.

Comment: 33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,91,92,93,94,95,96 this numbers are ASCII values for symbols this code restricted only ASCII code not Key codes

Answer (score 1):

When you use jQuery to handle key events the `event.which` property is normalised for you so there is no need to test for `event.keyCode`. In the case of the `keypress` event, as explained in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), `event.which` will actually be the character code, so there's no need to test for `event.shiftKey` - you'll already get different codes depending on whether an upper or lowercase letter was entered.

Also in your case where you want to allow just letters and numbers it is easier to test for valid characters than to list out character codes for invalid characters.

So your function can be much simplified:

```
$('.GroupName').keypress(function (event) {
    var charcode = event.which;
    if (charcode >= 65 && charcode <= 90        // uppercase letters
        || charcode >= 97 && charcode <= 122    // lowercase letters
        || charcode >= 48 && charcode <= 57) {  // digits
        // valid character entered
        $('#error').hide().text("");
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#error').show().text("Enter only letters and numbers. Symbols are not allowed.");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sVzR4/

Or here's an approach that doesn't test any character codes at all, it tests whether the entered character is valid via a regex:

```
if (/[a-z\d]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {
    // valid
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sVzR4/1/

Note also that the line you had:

```
$('#error').attr('class', ' display: none;');
```

...will not work to hide the `#error` field, because it doesn't make sense to set `display:none` as a *class* - you probably wanted `.css('display', 'none')`, but it is simpler to just use `.hide()` and `.show()`.

**Note that validiting on a key event is not sufficient.** The user can edit the field by pasting text via the browser's *Edit* menu, and they can drag'n'drop with the mouse. So you really should validate on `change` as well (or instead) of the key event.